# Avoiding DD anomaly without adding a return statement

Tags: java, android

I Have this code and I have to avoid the DD anomaly "a recently variable is redefined". But I have to avoid the creation of another return statement too. I have no idea about how to do it. If anyone can help me it will be really helpfull.

Code with DD anomaly

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {
    int returnVal = 1;
    try {
        final Process ping = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
        returnVal = ping.waitFor();
    } catch (final java.io.IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return returnVal == 0;
}
```

Code with double return anomaly

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {
    try {
        final Process ping = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
        final int returnVal = ping.waitFor();
        return returnVal == 0;
    } catch (final java.io.IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public boolean isNetworkActive() {
    try {
     Process ping = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
     return ping.waitFor()==0? true : false;
    } catch (final java.io.IOException | InterruptedException e) {
       return false;
    }

}
```

btw this is not how you test network connection on Android, here is a bit more helpful method:

```
public static boolean checkNetworkStatus(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);


    boolean networkIsMobile = false;
    boolean networkIsWiFi = false;
    if (wifi != null && wifi.isAvailable() && wifi.isConnected()) {
        networkIsWiFi = true;
    }
    if (mobile != null && mobile.isAvailable() && mobile.isConnected()) {
        networkIsMobile = true;
    }


    boolean networkActive = networkIsMobile || networkIsWiFi;

    return networkActive;
} // End of checkNetworkStatus
```

PS: I've assumed that pingFor == 0 means network and pingFor==1 means no network, if it is the other way around, switch them

Comment: Worked for me, I appreciated it a lot

Regards